# Composition API - Axios request in setup()

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inertiajs

I am experimenting with Vue3's Composition API in a Laravel/VueJS/InertiaJS stack.

A practice that I have used a lot in Vue2 with this stack is to have 1 route that returns the Vue page component (eg. Invoices.vue) and then in the `created()` callback, I would trigger an axios call to an additional endpoint to fetch the actual data.

I am now trying to replicate a similar approach in Vue3 with composition API like so

```
export default {
    components: {Loader, PageBase},
    props: {
        fetch_url: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        const loading = ref(false)
        const state = reactive({
            invoices: getInvoices(),
            selectedInvoices: [],
        });

        async function getInvoices() {
            loading.value = true;
            return await axios.get(props.fetch_url).then(response => {
                return response.data.data;
            }).finally(() => {
                loading.value = false;
            })
        }

        function handleSelectionChange(selection) {
            state.selectedInvoices = selection;
        }

        return {
            loading,
            state,
            handleSelectionChange,
        }
    }
}
```

This however keeps on giving me the propise, rather than the actual data that is returned.

Changing it like so does work:

```
export default {
    components: {Loader, PageBase},
    props: {
        fetch_url: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        const loading = ref(false)
        const state = reactive({
            invoices: [],
            selectedInvoices: [],
        });

        axios.get(props.fetch_url).then(response => {
            state.invoices = response.data.data;
        }).finally(() => {
            loading.value = false;
        })

        function handleSelectionChange(selection) {
            state.selectedInvoices = selection;
        }

        return {
            loading,
            state,
            handleSelectionChange,
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use function though, so I can re-use it for filtering etc.

Very curious to read how others are doing this.
I have been googling about it a bit, but cant seem to find relevant docu.

All feedback is highly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this now with `async setup()` and `await getInvoices()` and `<Suspense>` but it never displayed any content.

So this is how I'd do it, except I wouldn't and I'd use vuex and vuex-orm to store the invoices and fetch the state from the store.

```js
<template>
  <div>loading:{{ loading }}</div>
  <div>state:{{ state }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import {defineComponent, ref, reactive} from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    fetch_url: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const loading = ref(false)
    const state = reactive({
      invoices: []
    })

    async function getInvoices() {
      loading.value = true;
      await axios.get(props.fetch_url).then(response => {
        state.invoices = response.data;
      }).finally(() => {
        loading.value = false;
      })
    }

    return {
      getInvoices,
      loading,
      state,
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getInvoices()
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

This is of course similar to what you're doing in option 2.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you would do this with Vuex? Since i have no experience using it, i would love to see that in action!

Comment: I might write a blog post about it, but the documentation is good and it's pretty straightforward. https://vuex-orm.org/ and especially https://vuex-orm.github.io/plugin-axios/ . It's an a bit larger chunk as you need to define your data models and setup the vuex-orm "database". Try reading the docs and playing around, it really isn't all that dreadful, but a lot to write about, and later you just copy/paste for the most part. The advantage is, you have a single source of truth and once you read data from the server you don't have to read it again, if you don't need to.

Comment: @Guardian since you're using Vue3, https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/ for vuex. It's also straightforward, but I'm in the middle of something right now and just saw the notification about a comment. vuex + vuex-orm + vuex-orm-plugin-axios . It took me about a day to figure out. I'll get back to this eventually.

Comment: Fair enough, im gonna give it a go! Thanks a million!